# Is it possible to create or use a panel to control multiple lights?

Tags: light, lighting

Even if it's possible to bind all the lights' attributes to one (one controls all), something similar to a digital switchboard would be useful. Does such a feature exist?

Comment: You can use Drivers to do that.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm looking at the wiki and still unclear